# How does scoring work in Suika Game?

Tags: suika-game

How does scoring work in Suika Game? Is each type of fruit worth a specific amount of points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two fruits are merged, you gain points equal to the current fruit "evolution" level plus the amount of points you'd get for fusing the previous level of fruit.

| Name | Points | Level | Previous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cherry | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Strawberry | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| Grapes | 6 | 3 | 3 |
| Dekopon | 10 | 4 | 6 |
| Persimmon | 15 | 5 | 10 |
| Apple | 21 | 6 | 15 |
| Pear | 28 | 7 | 21 |
| Peach | 36 | 8 | 28 |
| Pineapple | 45 | 9 | 36 |
| Melon | 55 | 10 | 45 |
| Watermelon | 66 | 11 | 55 |

This was determined by analyzing gameplay videos ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOWNbbHfwY4), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFtmXUVlYp4)) and going frame-by-frame during merges. Fruit names were [taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suika_Game#:%7E:text=There%20are%2011%20fruits%20in,five%20smallest%20in%20the%20cycle.).